# AMPHTML ads not accepted by HTML5 validator

Tags: html, validation, jquery-animate, amp-html

Just created my first AMPHTML ad with Adobe Animate CC.

I tried to validate the ad with https://h5validator.appspot.com/

My ad doesn't pass the Advanced HTML5 check. I get the following error message:

*One of your HTML5 assets is invalid and cannot be analyzed. Please correct any malformed assets and try again.
More details:
SVG_INVALID*

Here is the source code of the ad. Would anyone here have an idea what could be the problem?

```html
 <!doctype html>
<html amp4ads>
<head>
 <!-- export v1.0.36-->
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1">
 <style amp4ads-boilerplate>body{visibility:hidden}</style>
 <style amp-custom> img {position: absolute;} body {background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1.0000);}
   svg {width: 300px; height: 300px; position: absolute;}     .hideForPreload { visibility: hidden; }   </style>
 <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/amp4ads-v0.js"></script>
 <script async custom-element="amp-animation" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-animation-0.1.js"></script>
 <script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body  >
<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics" id="pageView">
<script type="application/json">
{
  "vars": {
 "account": "No ID found."
  },
  "triggers": {
 "trackPageview": {
   "on": "visible",
   "request": "pageview"
 }
  }
}
</script></amp-analytics>
<div id="svgWrapper" class="hideForPreload" >
 <svg style="width: 0; height: 0;">
  <defs>
   <g vector-effect="none" id="l0" >
                        <g vector-effect="inherit" id="l0o0" style="transform: matrix(1.0000,0.0000,0.0000,1.0000,0.0000,0.0000); opacity: 1.0000; visibility: inherit;">
     <path vector-effect="inherit" fill="rgba(0,0,204,1.000)" stroke="none" d="M 300.0000 0.0000 L 0.0000 0.0000 L 0.0000 300.0000 L 300.0000 300.0000 L 300.0000 0.0000 "></path>
        </g>
                   </g>
  </defs>
</svg>    <svg><use id="o0" xlink:href="#l0" ></use></svg>
 
</div>
<amp-animation layout="nodisplay" trigger="visibility">
 <script type="application/json">
  {"animations":[
         {
           "selector": "#svgWrapper",
           "duration":"1s",
           "iterations":1,
           "fill":"both",
           "keyframes": [
             {
               "offset" : 0,
               "visibility" : "inherit",
               "easing" : "step-start"
             },{
               "offset" : 1,
               "visibility" : "inherit",
               "easing" : "step-end"
              }
           ]
         },
{
 "selector" : "#o0",
 "duration" : "2s",
 "iterations" : "infinity",
 "fill" : "both",
 "keyframes" : [
  {
   "offset" : 0,
   "transform" : "matrix(1.0000,0.0000,0.0000,1.0000,0.0000,0.0000)",
   "opacity" : 1,
   "visibility" : "inherit",
   "easing" : "cubic-bezier(0.3333, 0.3333, 0.6667, 0.6667)"
  },
  {
   "offset" : 1,
   "transform" : "matrix(1.0000,0.0000,0.0000,1.0000,0.0000,0.0000)",
   "opacity" : 1,
   "visibility" : "inherit",
   "easing" : "step-end"
  }
 ]
}
  ]}
 </script>
</amp-animation>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

AMPHTML is **not** HTML5.

Your validator should already have complained about the amp4ads attribute in the `html` tag.

Use the [AMP4ADS validator](https://validator.ampproject.org/#htmlFormat=AMP4ADS) to check your AMPHTML.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://greensock.com/forums/topic/14239-h5-validator-advanced-html-check-svg_invalid/?tab=comments#comment-98301
your svg tags (pay attention that there might be couple of 'svg' tag instances) are missing a proper profile description:

```
<svg baseProfile="full" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

The other error that I bumped into after exporting a banner using Animate (v.19) + AMP4ADS was 'CLICK_TAG_MISSING'. This one might be fixed by:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clickTag = "https://www.nasa.gov";
</script>
```